# Как можно ускорить алгоритм перебора?(Задача про капкейки)

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, алгоритм

Есть задача, решать можно на питоне или на плюсах, фото условия:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Условие текстом:

Ваша знакомая юлия приготовила n вкусных капкейков. Каждый из них обладает тремя параметрами - вкус, количество посыпки, количество крема, i капкейк имеет вкус ti, кол-во посыпки di, и ci крема сверху. Юлия не использует метрическую систему, поэтому эти числа могут быть равны нулю или быть отрицательными. Для кружка ей нужно взять ровно m капкейков. Пусть качество набора это суммарный вкус по модулю + суммарное количество посыпки по модулю + суммарноее количество крема по модулю. Иначе говоря если выбраны капкейки i1....im то качество набора равно модуль(ti1+ti2+tim) + модуль(di1+di2+dim) + модуль(ci1+ci2+cim) При этом т.к, Юлия сделала по одному пирожному каждого вида, капкейк можно взять не более одного раза. В первой строке вводится количество приготовленное и количество которое нужно взять. В остальных строках вводится вкус, кол-во крема, кол-во посыпки.

Я написал алгоритм, который на известных тестах отрабатывает правильно, но на других валится по времени, как можно ускорить?

```py
def max_quality(n, m, cupcakes):
    max_quality = 0
    for i in range(1 << n):
        if bin(i).count('1') == m:
            taste_sum = 0
            frosting_sum = 0
            sprinkle_sum = 0
            for j in range(n):
                if i & (1 << j):
                    ti, ci, di = cupcakes[j]
                    taste_sum += ti
                    frosting_sum += ci
                    sprinkle_sum += di
            quality = abs(taste_sum) + abs(frosting_sum) + abs(sprinkle_sum)
            max_quality = max(max_quality, quality)
    return max_quality
 
n, m = map(int, input().split())
cupcakes = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n)]
result = max_quality(n, m, cupcakes)
print(result)
```

Пример тестов и ответов:

```
5 3
1 -2 3
-4 5 -6
7 -8 -9
-10 11 -12
13 -14 15

ответ - 54

10 5
10 -80 21
23 8 38
-94 28 11
-26 -2 18
-69 72 79
-26 -86 -54
-72 -50 59
21 65 -32
40 -94 87
-62 18 82

Ответ 638
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148277/discussion-on-question-by-clark-devlin-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не самое элегантное решение, можно все сократить было в функциях, но уже сил нет. Краткое пояснение:

Пусть известно, что максимум достигается при каких-то значениях. Пусть в этом случае мы знаем знаки сумм t_i, d_i и c_i. Без потери общности будем считать, что они все "+". Тогда на деле максимум совпадает с максимумом той же суммы, но без модулей. А в таком случае мы максимизируем сумму значений t_i + d_i + c_i. Таким образом мы решаем задачу вида "чему равна сумма m наибольших значений из n данных".

Итого, нужно для каждого выражения ± t_i ± d_i ± c_i найти m значений с наибольшими значениями по этой величине и просуммировать. Получатся 8 чисел. Среди них берём максимум.

Сложность – n log(m).

P.S. Задачу я решал действительно для себя, а не на контест, да и в правилах нигде не сказано о том, что я не могу подсмотреть/списать/загуглить/etc.

```cpp
#define loong long long
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
  cin.sync_with_stdio(false);
 
  loong n, m;
  cin >> n >> m;
 
  vector<loong> t(n), d(n), c(n);
  for (loong i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cin >> t[i] >> d[i] >> c[i];
  }
 
  loong l = 0;
  // + + +
  {
    vector<loong> a(n);
    for (loong i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      a[i] = + t[i] + d[i] + c[i];
    }
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    reverse(a.begin(), a.end());
 
    loong sum = 0;
    for (loong i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
      sum += a[i];
    }
    l = sum;
  }
 
  // + + -
  {
    vector<loong> a(n);
    for (loong i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      a[i] = + t[i] + d[i] - c[i];
    }
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    reverse(a.begin(), a.end());
 
    loong sum = 0;
    for (loong i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
      sum += a[i];
    }
    l = max(l, sum);
  }
 
  // + - +
  {
    vector<loong> a(n);
    for (loong i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      a[i] = + t[i] - d[i] + c[i];
    }
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    reverse(a.begin(), a.end());
 
    loong sum = 0;
    for (loong i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
      sum += a[i];
    }
    l = max(l, sum);
  }
 
  // + - -
  {
    vector<loong> a(n);
    for (loong i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      a[i] = + t[i] - d[i] - c[i];
    }
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    reverse(a.begin(), a.end());
 
    loong sum = 0;
    for (loong i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
      sum += a[i];
    }
    l = max(l, sum);
  }
 
  // - + +
  {
    vector<loong> a(n);
    for (loong i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      a[i] = - t[i] + d[i] + c[i];
    }
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    reverse(a.begin(), a.end());
 
    loong sum = 0;
    for (loong i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
      sum += a[i];
    }
    l = max(l, sum);
  }
 
  // - + -
  {
    vector<loong> a(n);
    for (loong i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      a[i] = - t[i] + d[i] - c[i];
    }
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    reverse(a.begin(), a.end());
 
    loong sum = 0;
    for (loong i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
      sum += a[i];
    }
    l = max(l, sum);
  }
 
  // - - +
  {
    vector<loong> a(n);
    for (loong i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      a[i] = - t[i] - d[i] + c[i];
    }
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    reverse(a.begin(), a.end());
 
    loong sum = 0;
    for (loong i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
      sum += a[i];
    }
    l = max(l, sum);
  }
 
  // - - -
  {
    vector<loong> a(n);
    for (loong i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      a[i] = - t[i] - d[i] - c[i];
    }
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    reverse(a.begin(), a.end());
 
    loong sum = 0;
    for (loong i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
      sum += a[i];
    }
    l = max(l, sum);
  }
 
  cout << l << endl;
 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, писать 8 почти одинаковых кодов? проще набрать массив из 8n значений. Ну и сортировка + реверс, если можно сразу сортировать в порядке убывания, как-то напрягает... :)

Answer (score 4):

Ну, раз ТС дошел до решения самостоятельно и оно больше не секрет, не вижу смысла скрывать далее...

Решение имени Stanislav Volodarskiy (в его скрытом ответе) — https://bit.ly/3R5kJ6Q

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int n, m;
    long long best = 0;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector<long long> t[8];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int a, b, c;
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        t[0].push_back( a + b + c);
        t[1].push_back( a + b - c);
        t[2].push_back( a - b + c);
        t[3].push_back( a - b - c);
        t[4].push_back(-a + b + c);
        t[5].push_back(-a + b - c);
        t[6].push_back(-a - b + c);
        t[7].push_back(-a - b - c);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        sort(t[i].begin(),t[i].end(),greater<long long>());
        long long s = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j) s += t[i][j];
        if (best < s) best = s;
    }
    cout << best;
}
```

Comment: На этом сайте полный перебор - это не комильфо

Comment: да, этот вариант не проходит по времени :(

Comment: @rotabor Да я и написал, что "*при указанных ограничениях в общем случае перебор не справится*". Просто ТС просил код на С++ для варианта перебора.

Comment: @Harry в общем меня интересует правильное решение, дабы разобраться в нём. Потому что даже с вашим решением ничего не приходит в голову, как можно пройти тесты

Comment: большое спасибо за решение, но объясните мне, даже если я участвовал бы в этом конкурсе, раз он идёт еще неделю, этично ли выкладывать решения?)

Comment: @ClarkDevlin ...но вы же выложили?...

Comment: @Harry но я изначально не был против этого :)

Comment: Но теперь, после вашего решения решение прятать решения решением не является...

Comment: @Harry для меня да, а для реальных участников конкурса? Ибо судя по статистике вопрос пользуется спросом

Comment: Ну спрячу я свое решение, они воспользуются вашим. Какая разница?

Comment: `sort` -> `nth_element`. Минус логарифм.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Смотрю на своё решение, и понимаю, что оно отличается лишь наличием greater<long long>() в функции sort. Что даёт этот аргумент, если без него не работает решение?

Comment: Меняет сортировку в порядке возрастания на сортировку в порядке убывания.

Answer (score 3):

В финальном выражении три модуля. Их можно снять, получится восемь комбинаций знаков. Каждая комбинация - линейная. Достаточно выбрать *m* капкейков с максимальной суммой (с учётом знаков, конечно). Из восьми сумм нужно взять максимальную.

```
import heapq
import itertools


n, m = map(int, input().split())
capcakes = [tuple(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n)]
print(max(
    sum(heapq.nlargest(
        m,
        (sum(k(v) for k, v in zip(keys, c)) for c in capcakes)
    ))
    for keys in itertools.product((lambda x: x, lambda x: -x), repeat=3)
))
```

Сложность решения *O(nlogm)*.

[heapq.nlargest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) нужен чтобы выбрать `m` самых вкусных пирожных за *nlog**m***. Сортировка сделает тоже самое за *nlog**n***. На практике выигрыша по времени не будет: сортировка в Питоне очень быстрая (хорошая константа), а куча медленная (плохая константа). Выигрыш в скорости зависит от соотношения *logn* и *logm*. А *m ≤ n ≤ 1000*. Отношение логарифмов порядка десяти. Сортировка выиграет. Так что `heapq.nlargest` - искусство ради искусства.

В С++ есть [std::nth_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element). С его помощью можно избавиться от логарифма (ну почти). Сложность *O(n)* в среднем, *O(nlogm)* в худшем случае:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    int m;
    std::cin >> m;
    std::vector<std::array<int64_t, 3>> capcakes(n);
    for (auto &c : capcakes) {
        std::cin >> c[0] >> c[1] >> c[2];
    }
    int64_t max_taste = 0;
    for (auto s0 : {-1, 1}) {
        for (auto s1 : {-1, 1}) {
            for (auto s2 : {-1, 1}) {
                std::vector<int64_t> tastes;
                for (auto &c : capcakes) {
                    tastes.push_back(s0 * c[0] + s1 * c[1] + s2 * c[2]);
                }
                std::nth_element(
                    tastes.begin(),
                    tastes.end() - m,
                    tastes.end()
                );
                max_taste = std::max(
                    max_taste,
                    std::accumulate(
                        tastes.end() - m,
                        tastes.end(),
                        static_cast<int64_t>(0)
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << max_taste << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Стоило бы объяснить, что происходит , когда подмодульное выражение по факту получается другого знака, а не того, которого мы принимаем при раскрытии модуля. Просто это переходит в случай с противоположным знаком, который мы тоже проверяем, и это нас спасает.

Answer (score 2):

Вот моё решение:

```
from functools import reduce

def ps(cs):
    ts, cs, ds = reduce(lambda v, o: (v[0] + o[0], v[1] + o[1], v[2] + o[2])
        , sorted(ck, key = lambda o: (o[0] if cs & 1 else -o[0])
                 + (o[1] if cs & 2 else -o[1])
                 + (o[2] if cs & 4 else -o[2]), reverse = True)[:m])
    return abs(ts) + abs(cs) + abs(ds)
        
n, m = map(int, input().split())
ck = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n)]
print(max(ps(i) for i in range(8)))
```

Алгоритм описан автором вопроса в его решении.

**PREVIOUS**

Долго думал, но без перебора не обошелся. Были гипотезы, но ни одну не удалось доказать (контрпример находился быстрее).

Поэтому предлагаю решение перебором, но с накоплением сумм для оптимизации:

```
def ps(i, ti, ci, di, cupcakes, m):
    mq = -1
    m -= 1
    hj = len(cupcakes) - m + 1
    for j in range(i + 1, hj):
        tj, cj, dj = cupcakes[j]
        tj, cj, dj = ti + tj, ci + cj, di + dj
        if m > 1:
            tj, cj, dj = ps(j, tj, cj, dj, cupcakes, m)
        if (q := abs(tj) + abs(cj) + abs(dj)) > mq:
            mq, tm, cm, dm = q, tj, cj, dj
    return tm, cm, dm
        
n, m = map(int, input().split())
ti, ci, di = ps(-1, 0, 0, 0, [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n)], m + 1)
print(abs(ti) + abs(ci) + abs(di))
```

Используется рекурсия. Стека хватает на максимальное `m`=1000.

Comment: Да если бы не отрицательные значения и взятие абсолютной величины, все бы было просто :) А так — всегда можно придумать контрпример, который занулится именно из-за допустимости отрицательных значений...

Comment: При n=27...29 становится заметным замедление, при n=30 (m=20) время работы составляет уже 30 с.

Comment: А знакомой Юле хочется дать совет: не печь лишние пирожные, чтобы не мучиться с выбором :-)

Comment: Спасибо за решение! Пока не особо разобрался в самом алгоритме подсчетов качества, так называемого, но тест не проходит по ошибке результата

Comment: @rotabor ругается на ошибку выполнения, возможно ли что в лимит рекурсии упирается?

Comment: Я проверил, стека хватает на максимальное m=1000. Результаты решения контрольных примеров совпадают с результаттами решения вашей программой. Вы как проверяете? Что за ошибка?

Comment: там автотесты, входных данных я не вижу

Comment: Значит, не проходит по времени. Видимо, есть алгоритм решения со сложностью, например, O(N^2). Но я пока не нашёл такого. Станислав Володарский пишет, что нашёл решение. Подождём 11-го сентября.

Comment: Только что пришла в голову одна мысль, проверил это решение на крайний вариант, когда все нули. Выскочила ошибка. Внёс исправление. Попробуйте ещё раз.

Comment: @rotabor возникает ошибка на выполнении на тесте, т.е, это не таймлимит, а скорее всего лимит рекурсии

Comment: Ну, значит там такая система исполнения. Я нашёл решение, о котором пишет Станислав. Так что перебор для этой задачи - это не ожидаемый способ решения.